# SPLFileInfo: get filename without extension

Tags: php, filenames, file-extension, spl, fileinfo

I'm accessing a number of files in the SPLFileInfo object. I see a way to get the path, filename, and even extension of the file. Is there a way to get the filename without extension? Here's the code I've been working with but I'm hoping to get something more elegant. Is there an out of the box solution?

```
$file = new SplFileInfo("path/to/file.txt.zip"); 

echo 'basename: '.$file->getBasename();  
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'filename: '.$file->getFilename();
echo PHP_EOL;    
echo 'extension: '.$file->getExtension();
echo PHP_EOL;    
echo 'basename w/o extension: '.$file->getBasename('.'.$file->getExtension());

>>OUTPUT
>>basename: file.txt.zip
>>filename: file.txt.zip
>>extension: zip
>>basename w/o extension: file.txt
```

Answer (score 31):

I'm late and all the credits should go to @salathe being the first helping the OP, but here's [the link to PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getbasename.php) for basename function. Basically, you get the extension, then prepend a dot `.` and finally use the basename function to get the name, like this:

```
$file->getBasename('.' . $file->getExtension())
```

For fast reading, here's the PHP manual page's example:

```
$info = new SplFileInfo('file.txt');
var_dump($info->getBasename());

$info = new SplFileInfo('/path/to/file.txt');
var_dump($info->getBasename());

$info = new SplFileInfo('/path/to/file.txt');
var_dump($info->getBasename('.txt'));
```

Output:

```
string(8) "file.txt"
string(8) "file.txt"
string(4) "file"
```

Comment: This is such a confusing design.

Comment: Sorry for being late: what's confusing?

Comment: That it wants the suffix in order to be able to return the name without extension.

Answer (score -1):

I couldnt find anything official like the .net's - Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Here is what I'm using instead
preg_replace("/.[^.]+$/", "", $file->getBasename());

I've tested it with "file.txt.zip" to make sure it returns "file.txt", not "file"

Comment: `$file->getBasename('.' . $file->getExtension())` is how this should be done, not a regex.

Comment: @salathe Submit this as an answer because this is the correct answer to this question. +1

Comment: @crmpicco It was the best I could come up with too (read the OP carefully). I was hoping for something more direct and elegant.